# Converting C style for loop to python

Tags: python, for-loop, idioms

How do you convert a c-style for loop into python?

```
for (int i = m; i >= lowest; i--)
```

The best that I came up with was:

```
i = mid
for i in range(i, low,-1):
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for i in range(m, low - 1, -1):
```

Keep in mind `range` is exclusive of the `stop` parameter.

```
range(...)
    range(stop) -> list of integers
    range(start, stop[, step]) -> list of integers
```

The difference between this code and the C code is that in Python `2`, a `list` is being constructed in memory by `range` so for very huge ranges this could be a problem. Replacing `range` with `xrange` would not build a list in memory and make the code practically the same. In Python `3` this issue no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

`m` from where the loop start.

`l` where the loop stop, and range exclude last item so `l-1` and

`-1` for reverse array.

```
for i in range(m, l-1, -1):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = 20
low = 10

for i in range(m, low - 1, -1):
    print i
```

This will count down as expected:

```
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
```

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) takes three parameters, a start, a stop and the increment between each step.

Answer (score 1):

Where possible, the Python idiom is to loop over the items directly, not to count through them. Therefore an idiomatic way to count down would be `for item in reversed(list): print item` or to take a reversed slice `>>> someList[m:lowest-1:-1]`

If you are looping over items and also need a counter, Python has `enumerate()` to generate counting index numbers while looping. `for index, value in enumerate(someList):`

It's not always possible to do this, sometimes you are counting and not going over any other data except the numbers, and `range()` is fine - as the other answers suggest. But when you have a `for (int i=...` loop, see if you can change it to act directly on the data. Writing *"C in Python"* is no fun for anyone.